# Restore canvas from previous call of onDraw for ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Wow, this is frustrating. I'm really just trying to clear my `ImageView` before each time I draw on it.

I'm trying to extend Android's `ImageView` class into a custom `StatusBarImageView`. I provide a public method `setPercentComplete(float percent)` so that my activity can update the image accordingly. But every time I try to update the image by invalidating it and triggering it's `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method, for some reason it tries to draw the new status bar and it's text on top of the existing image rather than starting fresh. So the captions I draw using `canvas.drawText(...)` bleed over each other.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening / how to fix it?

I've tried several different approaches and none of them have worked.

I tried saving before the first time I draw and restoring before each subsequent time, but apparently it's a new canvas each time the `onDraw()` method fires, so `restore()` throws an exception that there hasn't been a `save()`.

I've tried using `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)`, but not only does that not work, it changes the background to be solid black for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
class StatusBarImageView extends ImageView {
    private float status = 100.0f;
    private Canvas lastCanvas;
    private Paint imagePainter = new Paint();
    private Paint textPainter = new Paint();

    public StatusBarImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializePainters();
    }
    public StatusBarImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        initializePainters();
    }

    public StatusBarImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributes, defStyle);
        initializePainters();
    }

    private void initializePainters() {
        this.status = 100.0f;
        this.imagePainter.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        this.textPainter.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        this.textPainter.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    public void setPercentComplete(float status) {
        this.status = status;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Erase previous status bar and its text captions before drawing new one
        if(this.lastCanvas != null) {
            this.lastCanvas.restore(); //throws exception
            //this.lastCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); // Doesn't work and makes background black
        }
        canvas.save();
        this.lastCanvas = canvas;
        //this.canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); // Doesn't work and makes the background black
        //this.canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); // Same problem

        this.drawStatusBarAndCaptions(canvas); //Uses canvas.drawRect and canvas.drawText
    }

    //...
}
```

And the `xml` just looks like:

```
<my.package.name.then.StatusBarImageView
        android:id="@+id/status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
```

Comment: Each time `onDraw()` runs, you're passed a fresh, "blank" `Canvas`. There's no need to try to erase the previous draws, or do the save/restore dance you're currently doing there. Just draw your stuff with the current values.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe the `Painter` class variable is my problem? The only reason I'm trying to erase previous draws, is because they're sticking around for some reason. My new drawings are just added on top of them. Maybe I have to use a fresh Painter object each time?

Comment: Nah, the `Paint` objects wouldn't do that. Are you somehow setting what you're drawing as the `ImageView`'s image? What does `drawStatusBarAndCaptions()` do, exactly?

Comment: A screenshot of the problem might help, too.

Comment: Craaaaaap. I made a dumb mistake. This was a simplified example, I was actually drawing several segments from an ArrayList and I was just not clearing that List between `onDraw`s. I guess I must have banged my head against my keyboard a little too hard last night. Thanks for your help though, now that I'm clearing that list between draws, everything's working.

Answer (score 0):

> But every time I try to update the image by invalidating it and triggering it's `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method.

Well, that's the way it should work. Any `invalidate()` would eventually cause `onDraw()` to be called.

In order to achieve the requirement you have, you may keep a boolean value, which will indicate you whether current `onDraw()` is initiated after `setPercentComplete()` call:

```
  

    private boolean flag = false;

    public void setPercentComplete(float status) {
        this.status = status;
        this.flag = true;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (flag) {
            flag = false;
            // perform actions for showing percent status
        } else {
            // draw other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I think maybe my question was worded poorly. I'm intentionally triggering the `onDraw` method by invalidating the view, but I would expect the canvas to be blank to start each time. Instead I'm seeing the previous stuff I drew on there lingering from draw to draw... if that makes sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am not sure this is an answer particularly to your question. If you want to delete your question, ping me to remove my answer.